# Running Ubuntu in VirtualBox and it won't detect a public WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualbox

I have a Macbook running Mac OS X, and I have Ubuntu running in VirtualBox.  I am using a public WiFi network on my Macbook, but for some reason my Ubuntu virtual machine won't detect it.  It was able to detect public WiFi networks before, but now it can't.  The network just isn't showing up in the network menu.  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: do you mean the network isn't showing up in the Ubuntu lists, or are you talking about on the MacBook itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual Machines can't detect wireless networks if the Wireless Adapter is actually built into the host machine - this is because of the nature of how Virtual Networking works.

By the nature of what a Virtual Machine is, and what Virtual Network Devices are, it is impossible for the Macbook's internal wifi card to be 'bound' to the VM in such a way it would have wireless network connectivity.

YOu need to connect your Macbook to that network, then have the Ubuntu VM connect to the Internet over a "NAT" type network connection device or a "Bridged" type network connection that is set to 'bridge' with the wifi card (in the VM settings)

---

> Okay, maybe I didn't phrase my problem very well. What I meant was, when I went to manually connect to the WiFi network within the VM, it wasn't listed as an option. Where it would normally allow me to connect to a WiFi network, it just says "Disconnected" and it's greyed out. – Zen Hacker

Unless you've done as I said in comments and gotten an external USB wireless adapter and correctly set up USB passthrough of that device to the Virtual Machine, you can't have the VM manage wireless connections at all, for the reasons explained above.

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't phrase my problem very well.  What I meant was, when I went to manually connect to the WiFi network within the VM, it wasn't listed as an option.  Where it would normally allow me to connect to a WiFi network, it just says "Disconnected" and it's greyed out.

Comment: @ZenHacker that's because the VM doesn't have the capability to *use* the Wireless card - the physical hardware is not made available to the VM in the manner you're thinking it does.  You have to have a virtual 'bridge' to make it work that way.  The only way to achieve what you're looking to do is to have a separate USB wireless adapter or such, and then let VirtualBox pass that USB device through to the VM directly.  Otherwise, you have to connect to the network through the Mac first, then either use NAT or Bridged connectivity with the VM via VirtualBox

Comment: @ZenHacker Perhaps you're not explaining your setup, but as I understand from what you've posted, you're trying to have your VM manage a wireless connection, using the Wireless Adapter that is on board your computer (and part of the Mac itself) rather than an external USB adapter.  That's not going to work.  Ever.  Regardless of virtualization solution

Comment: I have already connected to the WiFi network through my host operating system.  In the past this has made the WiFi network visible to the guest operating system, but now it's not.

Comment: @ZenHacker Double check the settings on your Virtual Machine's network settings - it may not be using the right adapter (if Bridged), or there may be other issues such as the "Networking" being 'disconnected' (virtually, that is, so check the bottom of the VBox window to see if there's a red X on any of the virtual interfaces)

Comment: I restarted the virtual machine and it's detecting the WiFi network now.  It seems to be connecting perfectly fine.  The weird thing is it's now registering it as a wired network.  Very odd.

Comment: @ZenHacker Thats because it is a ***virtual network interface*** exposed to the guest as a wired connection and the way virtualization in VBox works the Ubuntu VM *will never see it as Wireless* as I said here.